# JavaScript modules and web application plugins

Tags: javascript, webpack, es6-modules

I maintain a (PHP) web application that consists of an application core and several plugins that can be added to the core. Each instance of the application can have a custom set of plugins, depending on the purpose of the instance. The application core and the plugins are developed in their own respective repositories.

If a plugin is installed, it injects its JavaScript into the templates of the frontend. This may look as follows:

```html
<script src="core.min.js"></script>
<script src="plugin-1.min.js"></script>
<script src="plugin-2.min.js"></script>
```

The ordering is important because a plugin might use resources from the core or another plugin that was injected previously. Currently, this sharing of resources is implemented as a single variable in global scope which collects the resources that are "exported" by the core and plugins. In a plugin, a resource can be accessed and used via this global variable:

```js
var resource = myapp.core.resource;
```

**Now to my question:** Is there a way to implement the core/plugin architecture described above with ES6 modules (using Webpack or something similar)? I would like to use a more modern way of developing JavaScript or even use TypeScript but I don't know if or how this can be done. I understand that it might be possible to import some resources from the core JavaScript in a plugin but wouldn't this be compiled into the JavaScript file of the plugin, too? This would duplicate the code.

---

**Clarification:**

The core application and plugins are developed in separate repositories, e.g. like this:

```
core/src/main.js
plugin-1/src/main.js
plugin-2/src/main.js
```

The code for each repository is built on its own into a PHP package. A final application instance consists of the application core and several plugins which are installed as PHP packages. The JavaScript is not rebuilt when a PHP package is installed.

I could import some resources from the application core in a plugin like this:

```js
import {resource} from '../../../core/src/main'
```

However, this would duplicate the code of the application core because the core and the plugin are built separately.

What I'm asking is if it's possible to create a build configuration that is "aware" of shared variables between the core and the plugins. For example, if I define a class `Main` in the core, it could be built into the global variable `myapp.core.Main`. If I then import `Main` in one of the plugins, it could be resolved to use the variable `myapp.core.Main`, instead. That's how the current implementation works but it's all defined manually. Maybe there is a smarter way with modern build tools like Webpack.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "I understand that it might be possible to import some resources from the core JavaScript in a plugin but wouldn't this be compiled into the JavaScript file of the plugin, too?"

Comment: Webpack is a build tool. You cannot use it in runtime (unless you want to run a new build every time you launch your application)

Comment: @NaguibIhab Please see my clarification.

Answer (score 1):

The general point of packing your modules into a `bundle.js` is the fact that while they are refracted in the `src`, they are still bundled into 1 bundle file (sometimes you split that into a few for various reasons). Webpack knows not to duplicate code, that's the basis of it. I'll give an example:

**src:**

```
root/src
root/src/main.js
root/src/plugin1.js
root/src/plugin2.js
root/src/utils/util1.js
```

so lets say we that main is the the entry point to your app. It uses `plugin1` and `plugin2`, and both of those make use of `util1`.

**main.js:**

```
import plugin1 from './plugin1'
import plugin2 from './plugin2'
//... Do stuff
```

**plugin1.js:**

```
import util1 from './utils/util1.js';

export default const plugin1 = ()=>{
  //.. Do stuff also with util1
}
```

**plugin2.js:**

```
import util1 from './utils/util1.js';

export default const plugin2 = ()=>{
  //.. Do stuff also with util1
}
```

**util1.js:**

```
export default const util1 = ()=>{
  //.. Do util things
}
```

When you use webpack to bundle up this code, it will know not to repeat code. It will know also to do a lot of production quality stuff if you config them properly (and honestly also by default it's pretty good from the get go). The result would go into the bundle and either a generated index.html file (I recommend this method as you can start hashing the names of the sources and avoid caching issue upon updates.)  of a manual one.

**dist:**

```
root/dist/index.html
root/dist/bundle.js
```

**index.html**:

```
<!-- Would / Should have a script tag for the bundle. -->
<script src="bundle.js">
```

**bundle.js:**

```
// Here you would get a minified/uglified etc. version of your JS which is optimized according to the config. You will not get code repetition.
```

Comment: Thanks but the application has a different architecture. The JavaScript of the core and of the plugins is not built together. Please see my clarification above.

Answer (score 0):

Keeping in mind that you have separate repositories for core and plugins, I would recommend to create packages for the core and each plugin.
So, in the core you will have package.json with `"name": "@scope/core"`, in the plugin1 `"name": "@scope/plugin1"` e.t.c.
Then you will build all packages for example with webpack and publish the result or put it somewhere.

After that you can use es6 modules with `import` statement.

Let's say in the plugin2 you need to use core features and also something from the plugin1.

```js
// package.json for plugin2
{
  "name": "@scope/plugin2",
  "dependencies": {
    "@scope/core": "1.0.0",
    "@scope/plugin1": "1.0.0"
  }
}

// some javascript in plugin2
import {coreResource} from '@scope/core';
import {p1Resource} from '@scope/plugin1';
```

If you don't want to publish your code, then you can put it somewhere localy and refer to it in dependencies like

```js
// package.json for plugin2
{
  "name": "@scope/plugin2",
  "dependencies": {
    "@scope/core": "file:/path/to/core",
    "@scope/plugin1": "file:/path/to/plugin1"
  }
}
```

Comment: But here, again, the code would be duplicated, right? If I use some resource of the core in a plugin, the code would exist both in the core JS and in the plugin JS.

Comment: It depends on how you will build it. Modern building tools (like webpack) are pretty clever. You can have the final result without code duplication.
Even if you have several plugins using core and each other you still can have only one copies of the packages.

Comment: But only if everything is built to a single final JS file, right? The architecture of this application is different, though. The plugins are installed via PHP packages and their JS source is not rebuilt after installation (see my clarification above).

Comment: For each specific page you can build a separate bundle of javascript code. This bundle will contain only what is needed. Without duplication.

Comment: This would require the JS to be rebuild after PHP packages have been installed. Unfortunately that's not how the system works. Each package brings its own JS file(s) which are used as they are.

Comment: So, what prevents you from building js before putting in into the php-package?

Comment: I'm doing exactly that. But how to avoid code duplication as described in my question? If several packages use JS resources from the core application and are build separately, each package will contain its own copy of the core resources.

Comment: Each php-package can contain duplicated js code, true. But why that is an issue? If you build js for each page, then each page will contain only the code it actualy needs to run. So there will be no duplication in the browser which is actually important.

Comment: Each page may include the JS of the core as well as any plugin at the same time as described in the question.

Comment: What I'm trying to explain, is that you can build a js-bundle for each page. This means that there will be only one `<script>` on each page which will contain everything (and nothing more) that is needed for that page.

Comment: But that would require the JS to be rebuilt after the PHP packages have been installed, right? Also, I don't think separate JS scripts for each page are a good strategy in terms of complexity and client side caching. Anyway, it seems like this application architecture can't be implemented very well with the JS build processes that are currently common.